# have to determine all users home directories - tilde scripting problem

Tags: bash, tilde-expansion

Assume someuser has a home directory /home/someuser

NAME=someuser

In bash - what expression to I use combining tilde (~) and $NAME to return the users home directory?

```
HOMEDIRECTORY=~someuser
echo $HOMEDIRECTORY
/home/someuser
NAME=someuser
echo ~$NAME
~someuser
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 18):

**Safer**:

```
eval HOMEDIRECTORY="$(printf "~%q" "$NAME")"
```

Here the `%q` option to `printf` quotes and escapes dangerous characters.

If `$NAME` is joe, you'd get something like `/home/joe`. For root, you might get `/root`. For "abc;rm something" you'd get "~abc;rm something" instead of having something removed.

Comment: +1 for solution. Also, minor typo: should not have trailing grave accent. Should be eval HOMEDIRECTORY="$(printf "~%q" "$NAME")"

Comment: I like this solution because it overcomes problems with `eval` and is neat, clean, easy to read, and easy to debug. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to `getent`:

```
getent passwd "$NAME" | cut -d: -f 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Tilde ( ~ ) it's the same as $HOME so, not all the user will have as root to home the same directory.

But if you insist in using the tilde this do the work:

```
echo ~/../$NAME
```

See:

```
$ pwd
/home/oreyes
$ export NAME=john 
$ export DIRECTORYNAME=~/../$NAME
$ cd $DIRECTORYNAME
$ pwd
/home/john
```

Comment: This assumes that all users' home directories, including the current one, are siblings. This will fail especially spectacularly if the current user is `root`.

Comment: No guarantees even when not root.  For example, homes on CMU's Andrew are given out following the pattern `/afs/andrew.cmu.edu/usr##/$LOGNAME`, where `##` is a semi-random integer.

Comment: I like this simple solution since I know i will run this case without root, good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting difference between bash and csh, where ~$VARNAME actually does what you'd expect!

This is ugly, but it seems to work in bash:

```
homedir=`eval "echo ~$USERNAME"`
```

Now $homedir holds the home directory associated with $USERNAME.

Comment: That is indeed the way to do it in bash. Tilde expansion happens before parameter expansion, so the shell actually tries to expand ~$USERNAME into the home directory of a user whose name is literally $USERNAME, and not the contents of $USERNAME.

Comment: Just make sure `$USERNAME` is sanitized first and doesn't contain stuff like `; sudo rm -rf /`, 'kay?

Comment: @ephemient: Good advice! I'm surprised "little Bobby Tables" hasn't shown up yet!

Answer (score 1):

**BEST METHOD**

Required: nothing
(*n.b., this is the same technique as **getent** without requiring **getent***)

```
home() { # returns empty string on invalid user
    grep "^$1:" /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 6
}

# grep "^$user:" /etc/passwd | cut -d ':' -f 6
/var/lib/memcached
```

**NICE METHOD FOR ROOT LINUX**

Required: Linux, **root** (or **sudo**)

```
home() { # returns errorlevel 1 on invalid user
    su "$1" -s '/bin/sh' -c 'echo $HOME'
} 

# su memcached -s '/bin/sh' -c 'echo $HOME'
/var/lib/memcached
```

**SOLUTION FOR COMPLETE EXPANSION**

```
magic() { # returns unexpanded tilde express on invalid user
    local _safe_path; printf -v _safe_path "%q" "$1"
    eval "ln -sf $_safe_path /tmp/realpath.$$"
    readlink /tmp/realpath.$$
    rm -f /tmp/realpath.$$
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ magic ~nobody/would/look/here
/var/empty/would/look/here

$ magic ~invalid/this/will/not/expand
~invalid/this/will/not/expand
```

**METHOD FOR HARNESSING CSH**

This is a BASH script, it just calls **csh**.

Required: **csh**

```
home() { # return errorlevel 1 on invalid user
    export user=$1; csh -c "echo ~$user"
}

$ export user=root; csh -c "echo ~$user"
/var/root

$ export user=nodfsv; csh -c "echo ~$user"
Unknown user: nodfsv.
```

**METHOD OF DESPERATION**

Required: **finger** (deprecated)

```
home() {
    finger -m "$1" | 
    grep "^Directory:" | 
    sed -e 's/^Directory: //' -e 's/ .*//'
}

# finger -m "haldaemon" | 
> grep "^Directory:" | 
> sed -e 's/^Directory: //' -e 's/ .*//'
/home/haldaemon
```

You can combined the **grep** operation into **sed**, but since this method is sucky, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: It's not the same as `getent` because not all users are stored in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: This would be helpful for Mac OS X, because not all users are stored in /etc/password.  However, Mac OS X does not ship with getent which renders it a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

one alternative way

```
awk -F":" '{print "user: "$1", Home directory is: "$6}' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: This will fail if e.g. LDAP auth is used.

Comment: You want to use `getent passwd <username>`.  That will use whatever Name Service Switch databases are configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf (ie: /etc/passwd, nis, ldap, etc).