# Tilde in path doesn't expand to home directory

Tags: bash, syntax, tilde-expansion

Say I have a folder called `Foo` located in `/home/user/` (my `/home/user` also being represented by `~`).

I want to have a variable

`a="~/Foo"` and then do

`cd $a`

I get
`-bash: cd: ~/Foo: No such file or directory`

However if I just do `cd ~/Foo` it works fine. Any clue on how to get this to work?

Comment: Of potential interest to people here: [How to manually expand a special variable (ex. tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash). I strongly suggest that you **DO NOT** use any answer, either in this question or elsewhere, which directs you to use `eval`; see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do (without quotes during variable assignment):

```
a=~/Foo
cd "$a"
```

But in this case the variable `$a` will not store `~/Foo` but the expanded form `/home/user/Foo`. Or you could use `eval`:

```
a="~/Foo"
eval cd "$a"
```

Comment: Thank you! The eval cd worked. I indeed wanted to keep the "~/Foo" intact, so this solution works. At first I tried

    cd `eval $a` 
but that didnt work.

Comment: The usual warnings against using `eval` should be flagged prominently here as well. **Never** run `eval` on data you have not sanitized, or constructed yourself in a safe manner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work if the directory name contains spaces. `a="~/dir with spaces"; eval cd "$a"` => `-bash: cd: /Users/jack/dir: No such file or directory` :-(

Comment: @duthen: You could use the somwhat ugly variant `cd "$(eval echo "$a")"`

Comment: The sane and correct way to write that is `a=~/dir\ with\ spaces` or equivalently `a=~/"dir with spaces"`

Answer (score 18):

You can use `$HOME` instead of the tilde (the tilde is expanded by the shell to the contents of `$HOME`).
Example:

```
dir="$HOME/Foo";
cd "$dir";
```

Comment: What's the benefit of the quotes, if your name isn't "John F.", and why the semicolons?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that tilde actually expands to $HOME, which in my opinion is more readable anyway.

Comment: @userunknown, if you leave the quotes out, you're telling the shell to *do more things*, and those things all have failure cases. If someone set `IFS=/` to read a slash-delimited input, for example, `cd $dir` will misbehave even with no spaces present. Expanding strings unquoted tells the shell to string-split and glob-expand them. Why would you write code that directs the shell to do things you don't ever want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

A much more robust solution would be to use something like sed or even better, bash parameter expansion:

```
somedir="~/Foo/test~/ing";
cd "${somedir/#\~/$HOME}"
```

or if you must use sed,

```
cd $(echo "$somedir" | sed "s#^~#$HOME#")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work if you try to refer to someone else's home directory. `somedir="~jack/TMP"; cd ${somedir/#\~/$HOME}` => `-bash: cd: /Users/jackjack/TMP: No such file or directory` :-(

Answer (score 1):

Although this question is merely asking for a workaround, this is listed as the duplicate of many questions that are asking why this happens, so I think it's worth giving an explanation.  According to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06:

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> Tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion shall be performed, beginning to end.

When the shell evaluates the string `cd $a`, it first performs tilde expansion (which is a no-op, since `$a` does not contain a tilde), then it expands `$a` to the string `~/Foo`, which is the string that is finally passed as the argument to `cd`.

Answer (score -1):

If you use double quotes the ~ will be kept as that character in $a.

cd $a will not expand the ~ since variable values are not expanded by the shell.

The solution is:

eval "cd $a"