# "~/Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I've written this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="~/Desktop/test.txt"
echo "TESTING" > $file
```

The script doesn't work; it gives me this error:

```
./tester.sh: line 4: ~/Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tilde expansion not working in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/tilde-expansion-not-working-in-bash)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try replacing `~` with `$HOME`. Tilde expansion only happens when the tilde is unquoted. See `info "(bash) Tilde Expansion"`.

You could also do `file=~/Desktop` without quoting it, but if you ever replace part of this with something with a field separator in it, then it will break. Quoting the values of variables is probably a good thing to get into the habit of anyway. Quoting variable `file=~/"Desktop"` will also work but I think that is rather ugly.

Another reason to prefer `$HOME`, when possible: tilde expansion only happens at the beginnings of words. So `command --option=~/foo` will only work if `command` does tilde expansion itself, which will vary by command, while `command --option="$HOME/foo"` will always work.

Comment: @Mason - also, the tilde expansion happens _before_ the variable expansion, so when `$file` is converted to `~/Desktop/test.txt` you've already missed the tilde expansion phase. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions for the order of expansion.

Comment: Thank you. IMHO, bash variables, quotes/expansions are so vague and error prone: each type of quote mark(`'") has a different meaning and they change depending on the context. I'd like to know a method/trick to reduce these errors.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can also use `eval`:

```
eval "echo "TESTING" > $file"
```

The `eval` takes the command as an argument and it causes the shell to do the [Tilde expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion).

Comment: This is a **horrible** workaround for a problem which is much easier to solve without `eval`.