# Start IPython in a given folder

Tags: shell, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I use IPython 0.13 on OS X 10.6 and would like to do the following: I have different project folders e.g. `~/dev/proj1`, `~/dev/proj2`. Now I want to start IPython in one of these folders without changing to it. My first idea was to setup a new shell alias. In order to do so, I updated my `bashrc` with the following line:

`proj1="~/dev/proj1/ipython"`

Unfortunately it did not work. What I got instead was:

> ~/dev/proj1/ipython: No such file or directory

I do not really understand this error, because IPython can be started from any directory by simply typing `ipython`. And the folders do exist for sure. So, I wondered if there is a way to supply the starting directory as an argument to IPython like:

```
ipython start-dir="~/dev/proj1/
```

Any ideas to solve this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an alias like this:

```
f_ipy()
{
        cd ~/dev/$1/
        ipython
}

alias ipy=f_ipy
```

That you can call like `ipy proj1`, `ipy proj2`, etc.

Also, it is better to use `$HOME` rather than `~`. See ["~/Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8409024/1983854).

Comment: Thank you for your help and the advise on `~` and `$HOME`. Unfortunately this does not work, too. I got the same error `no such file or directory`.

Comment: Then we should go one step back: can you do `~/dev/proj1/ipython` in your prompt? If not, my solution is useless. From what I read in [iPython quick reference](http://scienceoss.com/ipython-quick-reference/) the project is based on the directory in which you are. In this case, can you try the code I just added in my answer?

Comment: @fedorqui your first version of this answer does not answer the question at all... Perhaps you should remove it

Comment: @drevicko it was the first version that then was improved. Thanks for notifying, just updated it. No need to downvote, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to start IPython in given directory:

```
ipython -i -c "%cd ~/dev/proj1/ipython"
```