# Testing for a file with a variable with `if [[ -f $foo ]]` doesn't work in bash

Tags: bash

After doing a `touch ~/foo.baz`, I want to run this simple code in my `.bashrc`:

```
bar='~/foo.baz'

echo "$bar"; ls -l "$bar"

if [[ -f ~/foo.baz ]] # This is the old code I want to refactor
then
    echo 'A: It works as expected.'
else
    echo "A: The file $bar is not there."
fi

if [[ -f "$bar" ]] # This should be the 'dynamic' replacement, but doesn't work as I wish.
then
    echo 'B: It works as expected.'
else
    echo "B: The file $bar is not there."
fi
```

It gives me

```
~/foo.baz
ls: cannot access '~/foo.baz': No such file or directory
A: It works as expected.
B: The file ~/foo.baz is not there.
```

Why is this the case? How can i use the `[[ -f ... ]]` syntax to check for files dynamically?

---

I already tried to change multiple things, such as `[[ ... ]]` to `[ ... ]` or `"$bar"` to `$($bar)`, `$bar`, ``` ``$bar` ``` (with one front backtick less, I don't know how to format it) and combinations of them. Non brought any different result. I also looked into [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20682162/16821502) and tried `-e` instead of `-f` among other ideas, none of which solved my issue. `bash --version` yields

```
GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

I expect there to be an answer somewhere, but I couldn't find much that was helpful or even solve my question. If this is a duplicate, please advise on how to look for it instead of just closing or providing a link.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: Removing the extra `[` and `]` to support POSIX shell then I ran `dash ./script` Also works as what you expected so, might be something on your end.

Comment: Sourcing the script also did not change my output.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem either.  I'd suggest adding a couple of things before the second `if` to see what's going on: `echo "$bar"; ls -l "$bar"` .  It's possible that your shell is not interpreting the `~` the way you're expecting it to: it's not being being expanded to the home dir.

Comment: Don't use `~` if you're unsure of how/when it is expanded by the shell. Use `$HOME` instead: just change your first line to `bar=$HOME/foo.baz` or `bar="$HOME/foo.baz"`. If you really want to use tilde (why would you? you already fell in its trap), then your first line should be `bar=~/foo.baz` (with no quotes).

Comment: Given your latest edit, the quotes in `bar='~/foo.baz'` will absolutely cause this problem (whether or not `$bar` is quoted later -- it *should* be quoted, but that's not related to this problem). See ["~/Desktop/test.txt: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/desktop-test-txt-no-such-file-or-directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I learned a lot and, [as yolenoyer commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897371/testing-for-a-file-with-a-variable-with-if-f-foo-doesnt-work-in-bash#comment132225242_74897434), the subtle difference of some single quotation marks `'` being present or not was the source of my error. They make the `~` not be expanded correctly, [aqn already commented pointing into this right direction](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1255828/aqn) and [gniourf proposed some solutions to that](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf), including

- `bar="$HOME/foo.baz"` (probably the way to go)
- `bar=~/foo.baz` (without quotes, other traps see below:)

> if you ever replace part of this with something with a field separator in it, then it will break. Quoting the values of variables is probably a good thing to get into the habit of anyway.
>
> - Quoting *[the]* variable *[`bar=~/"foo.baz"`]* will also work but I think that is rather ugly.
>
> ([by Michael Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409034/16821502), added formatting/applied info in *italic* by me)

Please consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/desktop-test-txt-no-such-file-or-directory) where I have obtained [the quoted answer by Michael Hoffman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409034/16821502) and  more details about tilde expansion. [His answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8409034/16821502) also showed me `info "(bash) Tilde Expansion"` (along with more information). [Sanghyun Lee shows a questionable workaround there:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15948962/16821502) `bar=$(eval 'echo ~/foo.baz')` *(applied by me).*

[More reading on tilde expansion can be found in this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/tilde-expansion-not-working-in-bash).

---

It's also worth mentioning [the hints of Gilles Quenot('s answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74897434/16821502) about how to quote variables. But "whether or not `$bar` is quoted later - it should be quoted, but that's not related to this problem" - wasn't the real issue [as Gordon Davisson commented. He](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) was also the one pointing to [this mentioned Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409024/desktop-test-txt-no-such-file-or-directory).

Answer (score 0):

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

```
$ cat file
bar=~/foo.baz
touch "$bar"

if [[ -f ~/foo.baz ]] 
then
    echo 'A: It works.'
else
    echo "A: The file $bar is not there."
fi

if [[ -f $bar ]] 
then
    echo 'B: It works.'
else
    echo "B: The file $bar is not there."
fi
```

```
$ bash file
A: It works.
B: It works.
```

Comment: Thank you for the (absolutely justified) hint. However writing `"$bar"` instead of `$bar` didn't change the error.

Comment: @sb813322 Did you replace `bar='~/foo.baz'` by `bar=~/foo.baz` as shown in this answer?

Comment: @yolenoyer Yes, I did try `bar=~/foo.baz` instead of `bar='~/foo.baz'`. I also provided [a community wiki here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74937880/16821502) where I summarize all the valuable input i received and some info I got from provided links.