# cd to a folder name starting with tilde (~) in bash script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to create a very simple bash script that does the following:

- Inputs the user to enter a project folder
- Sets the value entered in a variable
- cd to the folder entered
- remove the readme.md file

From what I've read around I've come up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the project folder path:"
read -e DESTINATION_FOLDER

cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"
rm -rf "$DESTINATION_FOLDER/readme.md"
```

The folder's path I entered was

> ~/Dropbox/myproject

And the error I get is the one below. However that folder exists and I can access it manually using the cd command.

```
./cleanup.sh: line 6: cd: ~/Dropbox/myproject/: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this might solve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/bash-problem-with-cd-using-tilde-expansion

Comment: Is the `cd` necessary? If you just want to remove the file you can do that without it. You would still need to force bash to expand the `~`, possibly using `eval`. After changing directory, `rm -f readme.md` would be sufficient. Also, you can use `read -p "prompt:"` to avoid a separate `echo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tilde (<kbd>~</kbd>) is only expanded to the home directory if it appears directly (and is not quoted). When you use `cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"`, the characters in `$DESTINATION_FOLDER` are used literally, including the leading <kbd>~</kbd>. Even if you had used `cd $DESTINATION_FOLDER`, the <kbd>~</kbd> would have been inserted directly, although whitespace and glob metacharacters in `$DESTINATION_FOLDER` would have been expanded. So there is really no way to do tilde expansion on a value in a variable. [Note 1]

Some people will suggest using `eval`, but you have to be very careful about that. `eval cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"` could have unexpected results if `$DESTINATION_FOLDER` includes a shell metacharacter. Consider the following, for example (**don't** try this in a directory which contains files you care about):

```
$ mkdir -p ~/tmp/foo && cd ~/tmp/foo
$ touch a few files
$ ls
a  few  files
$ x="~/tmp/foo;rm *"
$ # BEWARE!
$ eval cd "$x"
$ # OOPS!
$ ls
$
```

The correct way to do this is to expand the tilde yourself:

```
cd "${DESTINATION_FOLDER/#~/$HOME}"
```

In `bash`, `${var/pattern/replacement}` produces a string based on the value of `$var`, where the first instance of `pattern` (if any) is replaced with `replacement`. The form `${name/#pattern/replacement}` only does the replacement if `pattern` occurs at the beginning of `$var`. `pattern` is a glob, not a regular expression.

*EDIT:* In a comment, [Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/) suggested that it would be cool if it were possible to handle `~user` as well as just `~`. In the same vein, it would be even cooler to handle bashisms like `~+2` [Note 2].

Indeed. Unfortunately, `bash` does not provide a builtin which does tilde expansion. Or any other kind of expansion. So I think it is necessary to use `eval`, but that requires considerable caution, as mentioned above. I think that the best that can be done is to extract the tilde-prefix only if it contains no metacharacters, and only then expand it with `eval printf %s`, something like this:

```
tilde-expand() {
  (
    shopt -s extglob
    if [[ $1 =~ ^~[[:alnum:]_.+-]*(/.*)?$ ]]; then
      printf %s "$(eval printf ${1%%/*})${1##*([^/])}"
    else
      printf %s "$1"
    fi
  )
}
```

(The above hasn't been carefully tested. As always, `eval` should be treated with the greatest of caution, so please examine carefully before deploying.)

---

**Notes:**

1. In general, this doesn't matter, because most scripts take input as arguments rather than reading them from the console. Such a script might be written as follows:

   ```
   cdrm() {
     cd "$1" && rm -rf readme.md
   }
   ```

   then you would be able to invoke it using a tilde:

   ```
   cdrm ~/Dropbox/myproject/
   ```

   because the <kbd>~</kbd> will be expanded in the call to `cdrm`, so that `$1` will have the expanded value.
2. I've never used `~+N` tilde expansions, but there are probably people who find them *essential*.

Comment: Interesting idea with regard to the expansion, it would be the icing on the cake if it worked for `~user` as well. What you have said in the second paragraph doesn't work for me - try `read a; echo $a` using the input `~`.

Comment: Your second paragraph is not correct, variable expansion follows tilde expansion, so with `cd $FOO`, a tilde in `$FOO` would not be expanded.

Comment: @user2719058: 100% correct. My mistake. Fixed, I hope.

Comment: @TomFenech: Yeah, my second paragraph was wrong. I rewrote it. I'll give `~user` a think; it should be possible, but I'm not 100% certain how.

Comment: @TomFenech: I'm not at all happy about the added solution, but it's there.

Answer (score 2):

It's the shell that expands a `~` into your home directory when you're typing things into an interactive shell. It won't work from a script.

You'd need to type the full path in to get it to work. (It can be a relative path, of course.)

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash) for how to expand a tilde in a bash script.

Comment: But you can get it work using `eval cd "$DESTINATION_FOLDER"`.