# How do I pass a path to this Shell script?

Tags: shell, command-line, command, command-line-arguments

This tiny Shell script called `prepareFastaRef.command` is supposed to receive a file name I am giving as an argument, generate the path based on it, then run a command on that file. It looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

REF="~/Dropbox/phd/fastarefs/$1"
echo "$REF"

samtools faidx "$REF"
```

I run it from the command line with:

```
prepareFastaRef.command test.fa
```

But it does not seem to be able to find the file:

> [E::fai_build3_core] Failed to open my file
>   ~/Dropbox/phd/fastarefs/test.fa

The problem is not specific to the programme `samtools` as I have the same issue with others. And I can confirm 100% the file `test.fa` is in there.

What I find confusing is that this command alone works perfectly:

```
samtools faidx ~/Dropbox/phd/fastarefs/off_aa1.fa
```

So it seems to be an issue with how I pass the path from within the Shell script.

What am I missing?

Comment: Duplicate: [Tilde in path doesn't expand to home directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/tilde-in-path-doesnt-expand-to-home-directory)

Comment: Use this for your assignment: `REF=~/Dropbox/phd/fastarefs/"$1"` (Quoting not strictly needed here at all, but good practice in general.)

Comment: To diagnose something like this, you can run your script with `set -x` and you'll see that `~` didn't get expanded.

Comment: Or https://www.shellcheck.net/ would  have told you, as well.