# Bash script can't find a file using a if statement with -e

Tags: bash, tilde-expansion

I have a simple bash script that tries to find a folder, and if it can't find it, it gives an error.
It gets a argument and tries to find a folder in the .local folder called `menu`.
I have the folder, but it can't find it:

```bash
Permissions Links Size User Group Date Modified Name
drwxrwxrwx@     1    - lost lost  15 Jul 22:19   menu
```

My code:

```bash
if [[ $1 == "edit" ]]
then
  if [[ $2 == "" ]]
  then
    echo "Error: You need to enter a playlist name."
    exit
  fi
  if [[ -e "~/.local/share/folder/$2/" ]]
  then
    $EDITOR ~/.local/share/folder/$2
  else
    echo "Error: No playlist called $2 exists."
  fi
fi
```

I'm running it with the argument `edit menu`.
Output: `Error: No playlist called menu exists.`

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

Thanks.

This doesn't work using `-f` or `-d` too.

Comment: Please add a valid shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) to your script, then paste it at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement all the recommendations made there.

Comment: The tilde `(~)` expansion doesn't work inside quotes or when enclosed in double quotes, try giving the full path

Comment: See ["Tilde in path doesn't expand to home directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748216/tilde-in-path-doesnt-expand-to-home-directory). In this situation, you could use either `[[ -e ~/".local/share/folder/$2/" ]]` or `[[ -e "$HOME/.local/share/folder/$2/" ]]`.