# Bash programming: get name of one-and-only subfolder of given directory

Tags: bash

In [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I'd like to get the name of the one-and-only subfolder of `a`:

```
cd /tmp; mkdir -p a/b; v=$(ls -1 a); echo "$v"
```

outputs:

```
b
```

Which is what I wanted.

This works, because I *know* there will be only one-and-only subfolder inside `a`.

Feel free to assume this is guaranteed in all cases in my scenario.

What I feel uneasy about, is this recommendation from **[Bash pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)**

```
In addition to this, the use of ls is just plain unnecessary.
It's an external command whose output is intended specifically
to be read by a human, not parsed by a script.
```

This is even more intimidating and lapidary (from the same link as above):

---

**parsing the output of ls -- a utility whose output should never ever be parsed.**

---

It resonates with me but this, an *attempt* at using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) globbing, obv. does not work:

```
 cd /tmp; mkdir -p a/b; v=a/*; echo "$v"
```

outputs:

```
a/*
```

Sadness.

So, how can I get *globbing* for a variable assignment?

I *think* I know how to leverage *globbing* outside of assignment..

```
for d in a/*; do echo "$(basename $d)"; done
```

outputs:

```
b
```

"The right answer" (TM).

Could you kindly teach me how to *do this right* and explain the principle behind it too, please?

** NOTE: I don't like the output of this command:**

```
cd /tmp; w='name with blanks'; mkdir -p "$w/b"; v=$(echo "$w"/*); echo "$v"
```

which is:

```
name with blanks/b
```

I'd like to just get:

```
b
```

do I *have to* use `basename` afterwards, or could I get `b` directly, somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)

Comment: **I dispute the duplicate.** There are much finer points in here, about use of subshells, builtins Vs external commands, quoting of blank-separated path names, etc.

Comment: Where? I must be blind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty sure I wrote that pitfalls sentence. Anyway... yours fails because brace expansions, globs, and word-splitting don't apply to scalar assignments.

```
printf -v v %s */
```

And a little-known trick that will only work using the coreutils `printf(1)` (assuming there were multiple directories).

```
v=$(LC_COLLATE=C; /usr/bin/printf '%s\c' */)
```

Or alternatively, this is probably closest to what you're after (GNU find):

```
v=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '[^.]?*' -printf %f -quit)
```

See also: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Of course this is **much more elegant**! _Switching answers!_ Why more elegant? No subshell. `+1`. No need to `cd`. `+1`. Using a builtin. `+1`. **Awesome**.

Comment: @Robottinosino If you have a lot of shell questions consider joining `#bash` on Freenode. There's also the official `help-bash` mailing list, as well as the `comp.unix.shell` newsgroup. These have many more experts in this area than stack overflow.

Answer (score 4):

```
v=$(cd a;echo *)
```

Wildcards are expanded inside command substitution, and `echo` will output it so it will be used in the assignment.

The `cd` will allow you to just get the basename without calling `basename`.

Comment: Would you consider this superior or equivalent to `ls -1 a`, and why? One this is that `type echo` yields `echo is a shell builtin` so: not an external program..

Comment: `echo` is a shell built-in, so it doesn't have to run another program.

Comment: Right. That's absolutely in favour of `echo` then, completely agree. Does the `$(...)` command substitution spawn a subshell though, in the case of a shell builtin?

Comment: FYI, you don't need the `-1` option to `ls`. It only prints columnar output when writing to a terminal, and there's only one file anyway.

Comment: It probably needs to spawn a subshell to redirect to the pipe, but a subshell is simpler than running an external program because it doesn't have to find and load the program, it just forks.

Comment: I do because in my systems the _fine_ admins `alias` the `ls` command for me to something more articulate and "colourful".. so I want to be sure it runs as `-1`, not as _they_ like it.

Comment: Aliases aren't usually expanded in shell scripts.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that! You teach me something, _again_! Thanks.. Find it less cognitive load to "get into the _habit_" of using  `ls -1` though..

Comment: Is there any way to assign to a variable _without_ the subshell then? I might go "all the way" and learn it really properly, if it can be done.. Can it?

Comment: I don't think so. Filename expansion isn't done in variable assignments. See the PARAMETERS section of the `bash` man page for a description of expansions that take place.

Comment: So, could you edit your solution to cater for the last usage scenario I just edited in my Q for me to accept, please?

Comment: Of course. Elegance through simplicity. **LOVE IT**. Thanks a bunch for having me taught so much today!!!

Comment: The only exception would be if the directory was called, for instance, `.vim`, which would not be seen.. but I am **happy** with the solution nonetheless. Not a prob for me.