# Change directory to a path specified in a file with tilde

Tags: bash, cd

I have a file, say: `~/cwd`. The content of this file is a single line:

```
~/tmp
```

I want fo `cd` to this (~/tmp) dir. I'm trying:

```
> cd `cat ~/cwd`
```

And got:

```
-bash: cd: ~/tmp: No such file or directory
```

Why the RELATIVE paths failed? When the content of the `~/cwd` is absolute path - it works.

Comment: `~/cwd` is still an absolute path; `~` is simply a short-cut for the absolute path of the current user's home directory. It's intended for interactive use, though, not for scripting. If you have control over the file (and you should, if you are even thinking about using `eval`), then you should write out the directory name in full, in which case `cd $(< ~/cwd)` would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
eval cd `cat ~/cwd`
```

The '~' needs to be expanded by the shell. The eval causes the command to be run through the shell's command processing, which includes '~' expansion.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why 'cd `cat ~/cwd`' didn't? `cat ~/cwd` gives a string, and 'cat' should interpret it well..

Comment: Keep in mind that '~' is interpreted by the shell, not cat. So, "~/cwd" is first expanded by the shell to a path, and then passed to cat. The output of cat also contains '~', and this needs to be expanded by the shell too. The use of eval causes shell to run it through its command processing, which expands the '~'.

Comment: It works, but you'd better trust that file not to be malicious. If it has `$(rm -rf /)/cwd`, you're in bad, bad shape.

Answer (score 5):

It's not a problem with relative paths -- this happens because the shell evaluation model does tilde expansion BEFORE parameter expansion. Skipping back up to the very beginning of the evaluation process, with eval, introduces security bugs -- so if one REALLY needs to support this (and I argue, strongly, that it's a bad idea), a safe implementation (targeting platforms with the `getent` command available) would look like the following:

```
expandPath() {
  local path
  local -a pathElements resultPathElements
  IFS=':' read -r -a pathElements <<<"$1"
  : "${pathElements[@]}"
  for path in "${pathElements[@]}"; do
    : "$path"
    case $path in
      "~+"/*)
        path=$PWD/${path#"~+/"}
        ;;
      "~-"/*)
        path=$OLDPWD/${path#"~-/"}
        ;;
      "~"/*)
        path=$HOME/${path#"~/"}
        ;;
      "~"*)
        username=${path%%/*}
        username=${username#"~"}
        IFS=: read _ _ _ _ _ homedir _ < <(getent passwd "$username")
        if [[ $path = */* ]]; then
          path=${homedir}/${path#*/}
        else
          path=$homedir
        fi
        ;;
    esac
    resultPathElements+=( "$path" )
  done
  local result
  printf -v result '%s:' "${resultPathElements[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${result%:}"
}
```

...to use this for a path read from a file safely:

```
printf '%s\n' "$(expandPath "$(<file)")"
```

---

Alternately, a simpler approach that uses `eval` carefully:

```
expandPath() {
  case $1 in
    ~[+-]*)
      local content content_q
      printf -v content_q '%q' "${1:2}"
      eval "content=${1:0:2}${content_q}"
      printf '%s\n' "$content"
      ;;
    ~*)
      local content content_q
      printf -v content_q '%q' "${1:1}"
      eval "content=~${content_q}"
      printf '%s\n' "$content"
      ;;
    *)
      printf '%s\n' "$1"
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Comment: ~username doesn't work with variable:
`path="~root";
printf '%s\n' "$(expandPath "$path")"` returns `~root` not `/root`. But it's working if I do `printf '%s\n' "$(expandPath ~root)"`

Comment: I started tracing with `set -x` and noticed the unused variable `assetsPath` :D... thanks for quick response...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, considering the security implications of `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `eval`:

```
eval cd $(cat file)
```

Otherwise the shell will not be able to interpret the meaning of `~`.

Comment: Good point, @CharlesDuffy. What could we do? `comm=$(cat file); [[ ! "$comm" == *rm* ]] && eval cd "$comm"`?

Comment: I'd lean towards handling the case of a leading `~` by hand and discarding eval.

Comment: ...I've added an implementation of that as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without the need of `cat`:

```
eval cd "$(<~/cwd)"
```

Comment: +1 for not using cat, -1 for suggesting eval without a warning about trust.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Everyone did and it's just a trivial matter anyway. Besides, concluding that someone might not be smart enough to realize the possible consequence of using `eval` on a simple test file could only be somebody else's worry or opinion. Mine is also just an update for their answers.

Comment: If everybody else jumped off a bridge, would you? Seriously, though, the whole reason this question comes up is that folks don't understand bash's evaluation model (order of evaluation between different expansion rules). If someone doesn't grok that, then *yes*, it _is_ appropriate to assume that they don't appreciate the security implications of jumping back to the beginning of the evaluation chain.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For that obvious quote which I somehow expected, I did recognize the necessity of mentioning the detail about `eval`, but I chose not to for I didn't find it necessary enough for just a simple question. Again considering security in this kind of topic is just an opinion. And I hope you don't conclude that I'm imprudent for such matters. I had answered with many scripts in SO that make use of eval. Try to see if you can find a flaw in those. Besides this of course.

Comment: I'm holding you to a higher standard than most here because you've demonstrated a higher-than-average level of clue. Take it as a compliment. :)