# Bash path variable using ~ resulting in 'No such file or directory'

Tags: bash

If I do this:

```
ls ~/Dev/Project/Assets/_Core/
```

I get a super duper directory listing! Yay! But if I do this:

```
assetsPath=$(head -n 1 .config | perl -ne 'print if s/^assets=(.*)/\1/g')
echo $assetsPath
ls $assetsPath
```

I get:

```
~/Dev/Project/Assets/_Core/ # this was the variable value from the echo
ls: ~/Dev/Project/Assets/_Core/: No such file or directory
```

I even tried using `${assetsPath}` but that didn't work either?

Comment: `~` expansion happens before variable expansion. You can't stick it in a variable. Use `$HOME` or don't put it in the variable.

Comment: Ah! I should be able to replace the tilde in the variable before calling the ls yes?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. You need to avoid having `~` in a variable if you want the shell to expand it. `~` is a special and specific shell expansion. See the output from `echo ~root:~root` for example as compared to `echo $HOME:$HOME` for example. `~` should really just be avoided in general is my feeling.

Comment: Well, I'd like to support it in the config but I can easily just replace ~ in the string with $HOME

Comment: You really don't want to. It isn't equivalent. It is a shell thing (it does more than just expand to `$HOME` also). Just make them write the value out (or if you expand shell variables in there already make them use `$HOME`).

Comment: @remus This solution is not legitimate unless you add `if [[ $assetsPath == *[^/.~a-zA-Z0-9]* ]]; then echo "preventing bad things from happening!!"; exit 1; fi` before the eval.

Comment: Yeah, `eval` is only a "solution" if you include "adds a giant security hole" in your requirements (or do careful validation of the value you pass to it as @thatotherguy suggested though I can't, offhand, evaluate whether that validation is enough).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a partial solution:

```
assetsPath=${assetsPath//'~'/$HOME}
```

What this *doesn't* address is `~username` expansion; if your `assetsPath` uses this, then you need a bit more logic (which I think I've added in a separate StackOverflow answer; looking for the question).

---

It also doesn't address `~` in non-leading position, where it *shouldn't* be expanded. To handle both corner cases, I'm going to [self-plagarize a bit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310477/14122):

```
expandPath() {
  local path
  local -a pathElements resultPathElements
  IFS=':' read -r -a pathElements <<<"$1"
  : "${pathElements[@]}"
  for path in "${pathElements[@]}"; do
    : "$path"
    case $path in
      "~+"/*)
        path=$PWD/${path#"~+/"}
        ;;
      "~-"/*)
        path=$OLDPWD/${path#"~-/"}
        ;;
      "~"/*)
        path=$HOME/${path#"~/"}
        ;;
      "~"*)
        username=${path%%/*}
        username=${username#"~"}
        IFS=: read _ _ _ _ _ homedir _ < <(getent passwd "$username")
        if [[ $path = */* ]]; then
          path=${homedir}/${path#*/}
        else
          path=$homedir
        fi
        ;;
    esac
    resultPathElements+=( "$path" )
  done
  local result
  printf -v result '%s:' "${resultPathElements[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${result%:}"
}
```

...then:

```
assetsPath=$(expandPath "$assetsPath")
```

Comment: Thank you. Much better. I don't need to support the `~username` expansion, so this will do.

Comment: Ahh -- found the place where I went to the effort to do it right: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18742860/14122; copied that into the other question at hand, as http://stackoverflow.com/a/29310477/14122

Comment: @EtanReisner, ...one of those two is deleted over accuracy concerns, no?

Comment: @EtanReisner, eh -- I can't leave well enough on this one; putting some more effort into it.

Comment: @EtanReisner, I believe I've addressed the issues you mention.

Comment: Turns out I couldn't leave well enough alone either... so I did this: https://github.com/deryni/expandTilde.sh

Comment: the `read` will go screwy on backslashes, but i guess `getent` doesn't do those?

Comment: Backslashes can actually be used inside `getent` output when there's a literal `:`, so the lack of a `-r` argument to `read` here (which would turn off its usually-undesired backslash processing) is intentional; it ensures that IFS characters that are intended to be literal rather than field separators are parsed as such.

Comment: Is it possible to get a colon in the `getent` output from the `passwd` file or only from other sources of data (when configured appropriately)?