# Bash:script cannot be called after adding the path

Tags: bash, unix

I am writing my own unix scripts so I want to add a new directory for Bash. I add sth in .bash_profile like this.

```
PATH="~/Documents:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

and in my ~/Documents, there is a file named test of which the content is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
print("hahahhah")
```

I also used

```
chmod 755 test
```

to make it executable.

But I cannot call it in terminal directly. `./test` works as usual.
What went wrong?

After I change to

```
PATH="$HOME/Documents:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

nothing happens.

```
FDSM_lhn@9-53:~/Documents$ test
FDSM_lhn@9-53:~/Documents$ ./test
hahahhah
```

Solution:
The fundamental reason is that I have a command of the same name as default one, So it won't work any way! Changing name will be sufficient!

Comment: What's in PATH?  Does `~/Documents` appear, or the expanded version?  Unless it's the expanded version, it won't help, and I think the double quotes prevent the `~` being expanded.  Add `echo "$PATH"` after the `export PATH` and see what it says.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tilde doesn't get expanded inside strings. So by quoting the right-hand side of the assignment you prevent it from being expanded and get a literal `~` in your `PATH` variable which doesn't help you any.

You have two ways to fix this:

1. Drop the quotes on the assignment (yes this is safe, even for `$PATH` values with spaces, etc.).
2. Use `$HOME` instead of `~`.

I prefer the second solution but the first is entirely valid for this case.

Beware though that in places where you *aren't* doing a straight assignment you often **cannot** just drop the quotes and trying to use `~` *will* cause problems.

In which case you will end up finding a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29309632/258523) with an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310360/258523) and something ugly like [this](https://github.com/deryni/expandTilde.sh).

Comment: And of course, shadowing the system command `test` with your own unrelated program is always a bad idea.

Comment: ```PATH="$HOME/Documents:${PATH}"
export PATH``` is still not working. Do I need to restart the whole computer?

Comment: No, but you need to do that in the shell session you are testing or load a new shell session (assuming you put that in a shell startup file). What does `declare -p PATH` say when it isn't working?

Comment: Oh man, the first comment help me out. The command ```test```  shadow my own test program.