# Expand ~ in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I tend to visit the same directories during the course of a workday. Using the dirs -v command I can keep a list in a file

dirs -v > last-lines.txt

I would like to be able to re-read this file in a new terminal and pushd to each directory on the line. What I have is

```
cat ~/last-list.txt | while read line; do pushd $line; done
```

the issue I am having is that the '~' is not expanded and as a result the pushd fails with

```
-bash: pushd: ~/director-name: No such file or directory
```

Is there anyway to force '~' to be expanded to the full path, or a smarter way to accomplish the above?

Thanks

Comment: note you can say `while read -r line; do pushd ...; done < ~/last-list.txt` instead of `cat | while ...`.

Comment: My current attempt at a maximally complete answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/18742860/14122. That said, arguably the easier answer is not to support tilde expansion in your data files -- it's not a common feature in noninteractive use.

Comment: BTW -- directory names can have literal newlines in them. Reading them from a newline-delimited file, then, isn't exactly a great practice. (Also, they can end in whitespace, so you'd need to clear `IFS` during the read, and they can contain literal backslashes, so you'd need to pass `-r` to the read command as well, if you want to cover all the corner cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `pushd $line;` to:

```
pushd "${line/#\~/$HOME}";
```

`~` will be expanded to `$HOME`

Note: Use double quotation to handle white spaces in path

You are making useless use of `cat`. It's not needed here at all.

To read line from file:

```
while IFS= read -r line;do
#do something
done < filepath
```

A complete but more complex solution from  [Charles Duffys' answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740167/change-directory-in-bash-to-a-directory-specified-in-a-file-with-tilde/18742860#18742860)

```
expandPath() {
  local path
  local -a pathElements resultPathElements
  IFS=':' read -r -a pathElements <<<"$1"
  : "${pathElements[@]}"
  for path in "${pathElements[@]}"; do
    : "$path"
    case $path in
      "~+"/*)
        path=$PWD/${path#"~+/"}
        ;;
      "~-"/*)
        path=$OLDPWD/${path#"~-/"}
        ;;
      "~"/*)
        path=$HOME/${path#"~/"}
        ;;
      "~"*)
        username=${path%%/*}
        username=${username#"~"}
        IFS=: read _ _ _ _ _ homedir _ < <(getent passwd "$username")
        if [[ $path = */* ]]; then
          path=${homedir}/${path#*/}
        else
          path=$homedir
        fi
        ;;
    esac
    resultPathElements+=( "$path" )
  done
  local result
  printf -v result '%s:' "${resultPathElements[@]}"
  printf '%s\n' "${result%:}"
}
```

Usage:

```
pushd "$(expandPath "$line")"
```

`"$(expandPath "$line")"` is the expanded path

Comment: That works for the simple case. Doesn't work for `~username` or lots of other cornercases. There's an answer that's been copied-and-pasted 'round here that tries to cover them all; looking for it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy can I add your solution here, That's quite a legendary solution you got there...

Comment: Sure -- just provide a link back to the original.

Comment: Tiny quibble on quotes -- `pushd "$(expandPath $line)"` should be `pushd "$(expandPath "$line")"`.