# Match backed up files (`*~`)

Tags: regex, bash, match, filenames

I'm trying to match backup files in a script and then delete them. The backup files are the ones that have the tilde (`~`) in them:

```
$ ls -al
drwxr-xr-x 3 jwalton jwalton 4096 Feb 18 09:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 jwalton jwalton 4096 Feb 18 08:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x 5 jwalton jwalton 4096 Feb 18 08:54 test-proj
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jwalton jwalton  664 Feb 18 09:00 clean.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 jwalton jwalton  628 Feb 18 08:59 clean.sh~
```

My clean script has the following test, but it looks like I'm doing something wrong:

```
if [ -e "*~" ]; then
  rm "*~"
fi
```

What is the correct test to match a backed up file?

Comment: Test it by replacing `rm` with `ls`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your quotes that are screwing it up. It's looking for a file that is literally called `*~`. This works, but only if `*~` expands to exactly one file::

```
if [ -e *~ ]; then
   rm *~
fi
```

Why? Because the shell expands wildcards *first*. So if it matches nothing, it's equivalent to:

```
if [ -e ]; then  // false positive!
```

If it matches one file `x.txt~`, then it expands to:

```
if [ -e x.txt~ ]; then // OK
```

If it matches more than one file, `x.txt~ y.txt~`, then it expands to:

```
if [ -e x.txt~ y.txt~ ]; then // "[: x.txt~: binary operator expected"
```

It's worth knowing that UNIX filenames can contain any character except `/` and ASCII 0. So you can do:

```
 $ touch "*~"
 $ ls "*~"
 *~
 $ rm "*~"
```

And you can end up with files with awkward names such as `-r`.

```
 $ touch -- -r  # or imagine, your own C, Java etc. program
 $ ls
 -r
 $ rm -- -r
```

However, the `if` isn't really necessary. It's only there to prevent `ls` from giving `No such file or directory` errors, and you can suppress those with:

```
rm -f *~
```

Comment: The `[ -e *~ ]` will only work if the pattern expands to exactly one file; otherwise, you'll get an error about a binary operator expected.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to test it. `rm -f` (ignoring non-existing files) will do the job.

```
rm -f *~
```

Inside the quote, `*` matches `*` literally:

Example:

```
$ ls
*~  a  a~
$ ls *~
*~  a~
$ ls "*~"
*~
```

Comment: Thanks falsetru. The reason I am trying to match it first is to avoid the "*~ not found" error message.

Comment: @noloader, If you use `-f` option, `rm` will  not output error about that.

Comment: It is because `~` is not expanded within double quotes.

Comment: @fedorqui, Maybe you mean `*`? `~` is expanded to home directory (only when the word starts with it)

Comment: No (although `*` also can have this problem). I mean that `~` is not expanded when within double brackets --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963747/1983854

Comment: @fedorqui, According to bash(1), *Tilde Expansion*: **If  a  word  begins  with an unquoted tilde character (`~`)**, all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or  all  characters,  if there  is no unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix. ....

Comment: That's a good point! Also, note in my previous comment I wanted to say "when within double quotes", instead of "... double brackets".

Answer (score 1):

I guess using find is best:

```
find ./ -name "*~" -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: `find . -name "*~" -print | xargs rm -f` - slightly more efficient.

Comment: `find . -name "*~" -delete` - even more efficient

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recursively descend into subdirectories:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
rm **~
```