# How can tilde expansion be used to get a full path from Bash variable that uses tilde to represent a path?

Tags: bash, variables, tilde-expansion

Let's say I have the following variable set:

```
directoryTrash="~/trash"
```

How can I use this variable to create the directory it describes? I've tried using it with `mkdir` in the following way:

```
mkdir -p "${directoryTrash}"
```

When I do this, the directory "~" is created in the working directory and the subdirectory "trash" is created within it. How can I use tilde expansion to get the full path so that `mkdir` can do what I want it to do?

Comment: [Probable duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash).  Use `eval`. Or if that's offensive, `$HOME` is a reasonable, though not always complete, substitute.

Comment: If `$HOME` contains your home directory: `mkdir -p ${directoryTrash/#\~/$HOME}`