# Dumping Directories Shell Script

Tags: shell

I am new to shell scripting

I am trying to dump directories in log file using the following method:

```
echo -n "Enter Starting Point : "; read SRC
echo $SRC
find $SRC -type d >log.txt
```

The output of the above code which is supposed to be saved in log.txt, is empty. If I write following code:

```
echo -n "Enter Starting Point : "; read SRC
echo $SRC
find ~ -type d >log.txt
```

it works fine.
What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Have you seen it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash

Comment: What does the `echo` command say is in `$SRC`?  Is it a directory?

Comment: Problem Solved
Used the First code
instead 0f '~' i gave input as '/home' and it worked
:)

Answer (score 0):

I solved My problem by giving input as /home instead of '~' (without quotes)

Answer (score 0):

[Use More Quotes™!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) This script won't work with various inputs. For example, if you want to search a directory called `foo bar` (with spaces), the `find` command will instead try to look into *both `foo` and `bar`*, which may not exist.

Also, [`~` expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde) is not trivial. If you want to pass your home directory to a script it's better to use `$HOME`.

Answer (score -1):

~ is your home dir, so you dump the your home dir to log.txt, and 1st is your input dir to log.txt .

Comment: i know what they are used for but the problem is 
if i give '~' (without quotes) as input it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, as input it is just a char, but it is current dir in sh.

Comment: No, `~` is the current user's *home directory*. `$PWD` is the current directory.