# Using path variable with exists command in shell script

Tags: bash, unix

I want to see if a folder exists. In the script file if I use:

```
#!/bin/bash

batch_folder=~/Desktop/
if [ -d $batch_folder ]
then
    echo "Dir exists."
else
    echo "Dir doesn't exists."
fi
```

I get as result the correspoding echo. But when I prompt for the path with the `read` command I'm getting everytime that the directory doesn't exists even if it indeed exists. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -e -p "Batch folder location: " batch_folder
if [ -d $batch_folder ]
then
    echo "Dir exists."
else
    echo "Dir doesn't exists."
fi
```

I also tried in the `if` statement to use as variable `"$batch_folder"`, `${batch_folder}`, `"${batch_folder}"` but none of these works.

I know that the problem is in how the `read` command saves the variable, because in my first example, if I set `batch_folder='~/Desktop/'` I'm getting the same result as with the `read` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m going to assume you’re typing the tilde at the prompt. Expansion of `~` is a shell feature that takes place on script tokens and not on arguments or input in general.

You can [expand it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485157/707111):

```
batch_folder="${batch_folder/#\~/$HOME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, quote the variable:

```
if [ -d "$batch_folder" ]
```

Secondly, evaluate the content in the variable (expand chars like `~`):

```
...
eval batch_folder="${batch_folder}"
if [ -d "$batch_folder" ]
...
```

The first remark will fix the problem for dirs containing spaces, the second will resolve the issue of dirs containing `~` etc.

Comment: Alternatively use `[[ ]]` instead, then the variable does not need to be quoted.