# Passing pipe output to Test command

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed, echo, test-command

I'm confused with `test` command syntax. My goal is to check if file exists, but file path formed by `sed` command.

So, I try, for example:

```
echo '~/test111' | sed s/111/222/g | test -f && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

But that command always returns "found". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the currenty approach, you are just saying:

```
test -f && echo "yes" || echo "no"
```

Since `test -f` returns true as default, you are always getting "yes":

```
$ test -f
$ echo $?
0
```

The correct syntax is `test -f "string"`:

So you want to say:

```
string=$(echo '~/test111'|sed 's/111/222/g')
test -f "$string" && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Which can be compacted into:

```
test -f "$(echo '~/test111'|sed 's/111/222/g')" && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

but it loses readability.

And also you can use `xargs` to perform the given action in the name given by the previous pipe:

```
echo '~/test111'|sed 's/111/222/g' | xargs test -f && echo "found" || echo "not found"
```

Comment: Thanks! Now first problem is clear, but none of your solutions works properly. All of them outputs "not found", while file actually present.
I even shorted command to just echo command, and:  
`test -f ~/test111 && echo "found" || echo "not found"`  
works well, returns "found"  
`test -f "$(echo '~/test111')" && echo "found" || echo "not found"`  
returns "not found"  
Output of others is the same. If file not present - result is the same.   
Bash version 3.2, OS X 10.10.3 (just in case =)

Comment: @iMisanthrope Uhms, this must be because of the `~`, that is not expanded within double quotes. As seen in [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3963747/1983854), you can use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: Yep, you right, with full path all works as should.
Thanks a lot problem is solved!