# HDD partition space check using the path input from user

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I wrote a function which asks user the path and validates it; followed up by subsequent display of the HDD usage/available space for that particular partition of the drive which user entered path of. I am not sure why I am getting error

Code-

```
funcHDD () {
        read -p "Enter Path: " Path
        if [ -d $Path ]; then
                echo "Choose option from menu - HDD details:"
                echo "1. Used"
                echo "2. Available"
                read -p "Select: " HddUseAva
                tdisk=$(df -h "${Path}" | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1)
                udisk=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $3}' | tail -1)
                adisk=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1)
                fsys=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1)
                if [ $HddUseAva = 1 ]; then
                        echo "Current used space in $fsys: $udisk  (Total: $tdisk)"
                elif [ $HddUseAva = 2 ]; then
                        echo "Current available space in $fsys: $adisk  (Total: $tdisk)"
                elif echo $HddUseAva | grep -iq 'Done'; then
                        exit
                elif echo $HddUseAva | grep -iq 'Exit'; then
                        exit
                else
                        funcHDD
                fi
        else
                echo "Invalid Path"
                funcHDD
        fi
        }
```

Error-

```
Enter Path: /home 
Choose option from menu - HDD details:
1. Used
2. Available
Select: 1
df: ‘’: No such file or directory
df: ‘’: No such file or directory
df: ‘’: No such file or directory
Current used space in :   (Total: 20G)
```

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: @Raju added error in the body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use two different variables : `$path` and `$Path`, but `$path` is undefined.

Replace :

```
udisk=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $3}' | tail -1)
adisk=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1)
fsys=$(df -h "${path}" | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1)
```

with :

```
udisk=$(df -h "${Path}" | awk '{print $3}' | tail -1)
adisk=$(df -h "${Path}" | awk '{print $4}' | tail -1)
fsys=$(df -h "${Path}" | awk '{print $1}' | tail -1)
```

Comment: I am not sure why I am not able to use ~ as a path

Comment: `~` is treated as a literal string in scripts. A warkaround here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash