# bash - storing absolute path to a file inside a variable

Tags: bash, variables, path, absolute

I'm trying to figure out why

> [ -d ~/dir ] ; echo $?

indeed returns 0, if dir exists and is a directory, but

> DIR="~/dir" ; [ -d "${DIR}" ] ; echo $?

always returns 1.

> echo "${DIR}"

prints *~/dir*, as expected. I am given a text file containing path to another file, and thought I'd use cat to store the content inside a variable. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/27485157#27485157

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tilde expansion happens before the variable expansion, see EXPANSION in `man bash`. `~` is not a real path, it's expanded by the shell to the real path, but it doesn't happen for paths stored in a variable. Store the real full path in the variable instead.

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." Also, I was not able to accept an answer that soon. You'll get your credit, don't worry.

Answer (score 0):

not really a bash solution but you could do:

```
DIR="~/dir" ;

#expand the tilde
DIR=$(python -c "import os;print(os.path.expanduser('${DIR}'));");

[ -d "${DIR}" ] ; echo $?
```

Answer (score 0):

DIR = "$HOME/dir" would work fine.