# Issues using the tilde ~ in a simple function wrapper around scp

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I want place a simple `bash` function in my `.bashrc` that wraps around the `scp` command by accepting a 'source' argument and 'destination' argument, and so far have tried both

```
function send() {
eval "scp $1 user@annoyingly-long-server-name:$2"
}
```

and

```
function send() {
scp $1 user@annoyingly-long-server-name:$2
}
```

...but when I call either of the above a la

```
send file.txt ~/
```

I get the error `scp: home-directory-on-remote-machine: Operation not supported`. After echoing each argument, it seems that the **tilde is expanded into the *remote* machine's home directory** before evaluation. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Not sure that helps, but you might not need `eval`, just `sap $1 user@server:$2` should do the trick :)

Comment: I actually already tried that with the same issue; edited the question.

Comment: Does this work with explicit names? e.g. `send foo /home/luke/foo`

Comment: Can you enable verbose logging. Use "scp -v" and see what is happening inside. Might help.

Comment: @Oz123 ...it does, wow! Why would that be/how can I get it to accept the tilde?

Comment: @LukeDavis, I updated my answer. Can you accept it please?

Comment: Instead of `~` try using `$HOME` perhaps...

Comment: BTW, more correct than either of the above is `send() { scp "$1" user@annoyingly-long-server-name:"$2"; }` -- avoiding the `function` keyword makes it portable to baseline POSIX shells, quoting the arguments improves support for filenames with spaces, avoid `eval` moots [all the problems it causes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: Edited the question again... figured out where the issue lies, now just want to know how I can supply the function with a tilde `~` and prevent it from getting expanded before getting called.

Comment: @Oz123 Edited the question again... figured out where the issue lies, now just want to know how I can supply the function with a tilde `~` and prevent it from getting expanded before getting called.

Comment: If you want to avoid local expansion of the tilde, quote it at invocation time. That is, `send foo '~/bar'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ...or, apparently, escaping the tilde works. Or I can add a line in the function the parses `$2`, and replaces a leading `$HOME` pathname with a tilde `~`. Kind of overkill, but why not.

Comment: btw, "tilde is expanded into the remote machine's home directory" is what you *want*. What's actually happening is that the tilde is expanding to the *local* machine's home directory, but that home directory is of course not valid for the *remote* machine (which you intend to copy to).

Comment: Oh yup, you're right. 

And it makes sense that the expansion happens before it is sent as an argument I suppose. `~` is meant to only mean 'this machine's home directory'. Probably the simplest solution is just to escape the `~`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to convert back from the expanded tilde to the string `~` inside the function using [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash). The function is now

```
function send() {
dest="$2"
dest="${dest/#$HOME/\~}"
scp $1 user@annoyingly-long-server-name:$dest
}
```

In the second line, if the string `"$HOME"` appears at the start of the second argument, it is replaced by a tilde `~`. If the source and destination have identical `$HOME`s and the user actually **did** supply the destination path explicitly, it won't do any harm to convert to `~`, but if they do **not** have identical `$HOME`s, it fixes the problem.

For some reason it seemed that I had to assign `$2` to a variable before performing the string replacement.

Comment: I'll award you +1 for figuring out that the shell expands the tilde locally; but -1 for this convoluted workaround.

Comment: (I am plagiar... flattering @CharlesDuffy.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can use ssh-keys to prevent typing of passwords.

Before you use your function do just once:

```
ssh-copy-id remoteHostName
```

It is considered better to use keys instead of passwords for ssh and that is true for scp.

Second, you don't need `eval`.

```
function send() {
    scp "$1" user@annoyingly-long-server-name:"$2"
}
```

And finally, you need to use explicit path names:

```
send foo /home/luke/foo
```

Because `~` is some how not properly evaluated to `/home/luke/`.

#### update, side story:

If your motivation for writing the function `send` is really that `annoyingly-long-server-name` you should know about `/home/luke/.ssh/config`.
Inside this file you can do wonders:

```
Host a-nicer-alias
    Hostname stupid-host-name.verylongdoamin.com
    User luke
```

Then you can simply do `scp a-nicer-alias`

Comment: See my edit; without the `eval` command, I get the same issue unfortunately. And I'm aware of ssh-keys, this was just a quick example.

Comment: With the missing quotes, this will misbehave with filenames with spaces (and filenames that can be expanded as glob expressions and some other cases). Really should be `scp "$1" user@host:"$2"`.