# How can I replace a leading tilde ~ with the value of $HOME, or vice versa, in a bash string-variable?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, sh

The string variable here is the pathname to some file. Should be a simple solution, possibly useful to others.

This problem came up while I was writing a simple bash function in my `.bashrc`; see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45317559/issues-using-the-tilde-in-a-simple-function-wrapper-around-scp).

Comment: If you really want `~` -> `$HOME`, as opposed to the other direction, there's a **long** and comprehensive answer elsewhere on the site, but I doubt it's helpful to you. Which is to say, you should really specify only the direction you actually need.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash (re: question with said comprehensive answers which are almost certainly useless to you).

Comment: I wanted the other direction, but I just tried out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27485157/4970632) by swapping the `$HOME` and `~` in his parameter expansion method... and it worked just fine. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

#### `~` -> `$HOME`

This is duplicative of [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)

---

#### `$HOME` -> `~`

This is one of those places where you're better off fixing your users than adding workarounds (which are likely to have surprising effects) to your code. That said...

```
copy() {
  local src=$1 dest=$2
  [[ $dest = $HOME/* ]] && dest="~/${dest#"$HOME/"}"
  scp "$src" "$dest"
}
```