# git: How do I edit `core.excludesFile`?

Tags: git, git-config

The global excludes file is configured in `core.excludesFile`.

How can I easily edit this file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as it sounds.

If you have set:

```
excludesFile = ~/.config/git/ignore
```

Then you have the issue of [manually expanding the `~` character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3963716/5353461), which isn't as easy as you'd hope.

The following alias will do the magic for you:

```
edit-global-excludes = !"bash -c 'f=$(git config core.excludesFile); \"$EDITOR\" \"${f/#\\~/$HOME}\"' #"
```

This is equivalent to typing at the shell prompt:

```
$ bash -c 'f=$(git config core.excludesFile); "$EDITOR" "${f/#\~/$HOME}"' #
```