# Expand variable before tilde

Tags: bash, shell, variable-expansion, tilde-expansion

I'm sure this has been asked before but I can't find anything.  We have inscrutable login names on a shared machine and want to use shell variables to substitute the hard-to-remember login names for people's real names.

For example, let's say Omar's login name is xyz123.  I can do this:

```
$ omar=xyz123
$ echo ~$omar
```

and output looks fine:

```
~xyz123
```

but if I type this:

```
$ ls ~$omar
```

there is an error:

```
ls: cannot access ~xyz123: No such file or directory
```

I think it's because tilde expansion happens before variable expansion but can't figure out how to get around this.

Perhaps this answer is related although I'm not sure:
[How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash)

Comment: For reference: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/tilde

Comment: The output looks "fine" `~xyz123` but it is not the path to `xyz123` home directory.

Comment: None of the possible workarounds are very attractive.  Muttering terms of abuse such as `eval` won't endear me to the security folks — and there's no blame to them for that.

Comment: There's a lot of overlap between this and [How to manually expand a special variable (ex: ~ tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash); some answers, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/30770111/14122 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/29310477/14122, are directly on-point.

Comment: Taking a step *way* back, I'd say it's rare to need someone *else's* home directory, which isn't necessarily accessible by someone else anyway. Either the script will be run by `omar`, in which case you'll just use `~`, or the script will be run as root, who can just use `su` to become `omar` as necessary.

Comment: You might want to use the `cdable_vars` option instead; add a variable like `omarhome=/home/omar` (look it up manually once and store the value in the variable), then `cd omarhome` will be equivalent to `cd "$omarhome"`. (Other commands, of course, will have to use the variable more explicitly, e.g. `ls "$omarhome"`.)

Comment: @chepner  It's not rare on shared machines where you work closely with others and is why the syntax `~other_user` exists in addition to plain `~` (well, I assume that's why it exists)

Comment: @chepner  yeah, just writing out the path (w/ or w/o cdable_vars) is perhaps the most obvious and simplest way.  Maybe the best too  ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bash expands the tilde *before* the variable. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions

The shell will see if the literal characters `$` `o` `m` `a` `r`  are a login name. As they are not, the tilde is not expanded. The shell eventually sees `$omar` as a variable and substitutes that. It then hands the expanded word `~xyz123` to `echo` which just prints it.

Similarly, it hands the word `~xyz123` to `ls`. Since ls does not do its own tilde expansion, it is looking for a file in your current directory named `~xyz123` with a literal tilde. Since such a file does not exist you get that error.

If you want `ls ~$var` to list files, you need `eval ls ~$var`. Or, since eval is considered very unsafe to use casually, you could do this instead:

```
ls "$(getent passwd "$omar" | cut -d: -f6)"
```

Comment: eg `home() { getent passwd ${1:?Missing user name} | cut -f6 -d:; }` followed by --   eg `ls "$(home $omar)"`. Not as convenient as `~` certainly, but safest.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with checking if `"$omar"` is a valid user with `id` and then using `eval` to force double expansion. So protect against evil `eval` and then do it.

```
if ! id "$omar" >/dev/null 2>&1; 
   echo "Error: user with the name $omar does not exist!" >&2
   exit 1
fi
eval echo "\"~$omar\""
```