# Changing directory from the result of a command

Tags: bash, echo, cd

I am having issues getting `cd` to change directory given the output of a command.

For example, the following does not work:

```
# should be equivalent to "cd ~"
cd $(echo "~")
# should be equivalent to "cd ~/go"
cd $(echo "~/go")
```

Both returning an error such as

```
cd: no such file or directory: ~
cd: no such file or directory: ~/go
```

However, I am able to specify absolute paths, such as

```
cd $(echo "/Users/olly")
```

which will successfully change directory to that location. What's more, if I omit the quotes it will work.

```
cd $(echo ~)
```

At the moment, I have a program, `jump-config`, which will print the string of a path to the terminal.

```
jump-config
// prints ~/go/src/gitlab.com/ollybritton/jump/jump-config
```

I am attempting to do

```
cd $(jump-config)
```

but I am getting the error

```
cd: no such file or directory: ~/go/src/gitlab.com/ollybritton/jump/jump-config
```

I would be happy to do `cd $JUMP_CONFIG`, however, the program's output is not fixed and I need `cd $(jump-config)` to change.

I appreciate any explanation of the problem or help in advance.

Comment: You don't need command substitution to see this. `dir='~'; cd "$dir"` and you have the same issue.

Comment: To explain *why* it works if you emit the quotes, btw -- in that case, `echo` doesn't emit `~`, it emits `/Users/olly` (because the shell replaces `~` with `/Users/olly` before `echo` is even started).

Comment: (ugh, s/emit/omit/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tilde expansion doesn't work in quotes, and should generally be avoided in scripting. It's intended for interactive use only. From `man bash`, `/ *Tilde Expansion`:

> If  a  word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~'), all of the characters preceding the first unquoted slash (or all characters, if  there  is  no
>        unquoted slash) are considered a tilde-prefix.  If none of the characters in
>        the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the
>        tilde  are  treated as a possible login name.  If this login name is the null
>        string, the tilde is replaced with the value of the shell parameter HOME.  If
>        HOME  is unset, the home directory of the user executing the shell is substituted instead.  Otherwise, the tilde-prefix is replaced with the home  directory associated with the specified login name.

Would it be possible to modify `jump-config` to output `$HOME` in place of `~`? If not, you could try one of these options:

```
jump_config=$(jump-config); cd "${jump_config//\~/$HOME}"
```

or

```
cd "$(jump-config |sed 's/~/$HOME/')"
```

Comment: Better to quote the output of the command substitution or directory names with spaces will fail badly.

Comment: BTW, the current answer works for `~/`, but not `~username/` or `~-/` or `~+/`, all of which have special meanings to the shell. One rather ugly but comprehensive approach is available in my answer to [How to manually expand a special variable (ex. tilde) in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/29310477#29310477)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `foo=$(echo foo bar); echo $foo`

Comment: I don't know what your comment is supposed to prove. `foo='foo bar'; echo $foo` passes *two separate* arguments to `echo` (which it then separates with spaces in its output), but `cd` expects *only one* argument, whether that argument contains literal spaces or not.

Comment: In order to solve the problem I ended up doing `eval cd $(jump-config)` This answer did put me on the right path, thanks.