# Use value of variable literally in if statement (bash)

Tags: bash, macos, if-statement

I need to check if the value of a variable is a path that exists. This is being read from a text file.

Basically, the point I'm stuck at, the `line` variable is as follows: `location_of_folder=~/Desktop/folder\ with\ spaces`

I need to check if the path after `location_of_folder=` exists.

Here's what I've tried:

```
foo="${line#'location_of_folder='}"
if ! [[ -d "${foo}" ]]
then
  echo 'This path exists.'
else
  echo 'This path does not exist.'
fi
```

⁤

```
if ! [[ -d "${line#'location_of_folder='}" ]]
then
  echo 'This path exists.'
else
  echo 'This path does not exist.'
fi
```

However both say the path is nonexistant, which is indeed not true.

And yes, inside of the text file I'm reading from looks like:

```
location_of_folder=~/Desktop/folder\ with\ spaces
```

Using bash 3.2.57(1)-release under OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

Thank you.

Comment: Drop the single quotes; they are being treated literally.

Comment: chepner I..wait what? That works? How? I thought single quoting the `location_of_folder=` was necessary.

Comment: Hm. Actually, there are at best unnecessary.

Comment: What are they being interpreted as?

Comment: How exactly are you setting the value of `line`?

Comment: `line` is set from using `while read -r line; do .......; done < text_file.txt`

Comment: You probably shouldn't have backslashes there. That said, we really need a [mcve].

Comment: How are you reading the path?  If you are using `-r`, then you probably have literal backslashes in the name.  Inspect the value in the variable.

Comment: Ah, just saw your comment.  Stop using `-r`.

Comment: The name of the directory doesn't actually have backslashes in it; those are shell syntax to make sure the spaces are treated as part of the name in the assignment to `location_of_folder`. They are preserved in the value of `line` by `read -r`, which means `${line#...}` doesn't contain the actual name of your directory.

Comment: Yes, my `folder\ with\ spaces` has escaped spaces.

Comment: You would probably be better off using `declare "$line"` to actually define a variable named `location_of_folder` in your script, then use `[ -d "$location_of_folder" ]`. (That's not without its risks, but it ensures that you look for the directory intended by whoever wrote `location_of_folder=~/Desktop/folder\ with\ spaces` in the first place. It will also continue to work if the line gets changed to `location_of_folder=~/Desktop/"folder with spaces"`.)

Comment: I thought on doing that, however since it is a config file I am reading from I wanted to make sure the user-defined/manually user-written value was not incorrectly written or harmful.

Comment: At what point in this process do you expect `~` to be converted to a path to your home directory?  That is probably (almost certainly) not getting expanded.

Comment: William Pursell the first instance, when it is checking it with `if`

Comment: add `set -x` a line before your `if` statement and turn off debugging with `set +x` the line after `fi`. Now you can see exactly what values are being processed inside of the `if` (although it's not a straightforward read). Good luck.

Comment: `~` is basically never appropriate for use in shell scripts. Use `$HOME` instead, which -- unlike `~` -- is actually expanded in double quotes.

Comment: That said, your problem is more about `~` expansion than anything else, and we have lots of duplicates covering that space.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really an answer, but comments are hard to format.  There are several issues here, and the sequence below demonstrates some of them.  Note that there are blatant bad practices here (do not use `eval`, but that's essentially what you need if you want to expand that `~` to a path).

```
$ cat input
location_of_folder=~/Desktop/directory\ with\ spaces
location_of_folder=$HOME/Desktop/directory\ with\ spaces
$ while IFS== read -r name path; do if eval "test -d $path"; then echo "$path" exists; else echo "$path" does not exist; fi;  done < input
~/Desktop/directory\ with\ spaces exists
$HOME/Desktop/directory\ with\ spaces exists
$ while IFS== read name path; do if test -d "$path"; then echo "$path" exists; else echo "$path" does not exist; fi;  done < input
~/Desktop/directory with spaces does not exist
$HOME/Desktop/directory with spaces does not exist
$ while IFS== read name path; do if eval test -d "$path"; then echo "$path" exists; else echo "$path" does not exist; fi;  done < input
bash: test: too many arguments
~/Desktop/directory with spaces does not exist
bash: test: too many arguments
$HOME/Desktop/directory with spaces does not exist
$ while IFS== read name path; do if eval "test -d \"$path\""; then echo "$path" exists; else echo "$path" does not exist; fi;  done < input
~/Desktop/directory with spaces does not exist
$HOME/Desktop/directory with spaces exists
```

Well, this is sort of an answer I guess, since the first line appears to give you what you want.  But using eval just to expand `~` is a terrible idea.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash/29310477#29310477

Comment: Would it be better to tell the user to only input `"${HOME}"` instead of `~`, and then craft a way to check to make sure it does not contain a literal `~` (in case the user does it anyway)?

Comment: If you're going to check for a ~, you might as well just expand it yourself.

Comment: @leetbacoon, how is the user entering that input? If they're passing it, say, on your program's command line, `~` will be expanded before your program is ever started... *if* it's unquoted. If the user is quoting it, that's *their* problem, and will break lots of other programs too (you can't `ls "~"` successfully, f/e).

Comment: ...oh, a config file. If you `source` that config file, the `~` will be expanded, though of course that requires that you trust its contents to be safe to run as code. If you *don't* trust it, there are some tricks that can be played with rbash, but I don't much recommend them.

Comment: See https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/bees/blob/uuid-independent-wrapper/scripts/beesd.in#L54-L60 for an example of the aforementioned style of hackery to semi-safely eval an arbitrary config file (more safely than `eval`ing or `source`ing it, anyhow).