# Copying a directory

Tags: bash, scripting

I am totally new to bash scripting but wanted to give it a try. I wrote a simple and quick script for a backup of a directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter your source"
read source

echo "Enter your target"
read target

backup(){
    cp -r $source $target
}

backup source target

exit 0
```

However, once I run it it doesn't recognize the directory path. It gives out: `cp: cannot stat '~/Desktop/week46': No such file or directory` Even though the directory exists and when i manually run `cp -r ~/Desktop/week46 ~/Desktop/week47` it is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you executed it as a bash script? You are posting just the content of the script, but not how you run it.

Comment: Well i guess so. First line of the file is: #!/bin/bash and i execute it like ./filename

Comment: This may be in relation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash

Comment: ... but I guess tilde doesn't expand when using `read`. Google _bash tilde expansion_ and you'll find resources.

Comment: @JamesBrown : IMO, you should post this as answer, because this really looks like the explanation for the problem.

Comment: @HBJesus : From a programming design, asking the user for input from a script is rarely a good choice. Why don't you take `source` and `target` from the parameters? This also saves you from the tilde-expansion-problem.

Comment: Rather mark this as a duplicate if someone finds a better explanation. I tried looking but didn't find any - which would leave a place for a nice answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is unable to resolve the directory path because the read function reads the input as string in singlequotes (hence it won't interpolate/expand it's contents). So what it's executing is equivalent to `cp -r '~/Desktop/week46' '~/Desktop/week47'`.

When you execute in shell you are passing without quotes, so the shell can easily resolve the relative paths.

What you can give a try is exploring some workarounds with `readlink` `dirname` and `basename`.

One possible solution might be:

```
RES_PATH=$(readlink $(dirname $source))
FILE=$(basename $source)
SRC=${RES_PATH}/${FILE}
```