# Run command for each line in file while file content is parameter

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have a file that contains path names to directories like this:

```plaintext
~/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/.../a/
~/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/.../b/
...
~/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/.../z/
```

Wanted steps:

- Open textfile
- Fetch a line
- Pass it to command "ls"
- Pipe output and exclude all occurrences of ending "jpg" or "JPG"
- Route result into a new textfile (e.g. "_command_output.log")

I was playing around with `xargs`, but could not make it run.

Here is what I have so far: List files and exclude all "jpg" or "JPG" results.

```bash
ls ~/subdirectory1/subdirectory2/.../a/ | awk '!/(jpg|JPG)/'
```

I put that into a loop:

```bash
for i in $(cat ~/textfile-with-pathnames.txt) do
   #do your stuff to $i here
   ##xargs ls;
   ls ${i} | awk '!/(jpg|JPG)/' 
done
```

Another try:

```bash
cat ~/textfile-with-pathnames.txt  | while read line; 
do 
   ls "$line" | awk '!(jpg|JPG)'; 
done
```

How can I run an argument for each line in the file and use the file content as parameter/argument?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution (to my knowledge, this is fully POSIX compliant):

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while read -r line; do
    # Expand ~ in line (see below if you want details on how this works)
    line="$line/"
    line="${HOME}/${line#"~/"}"

    # ls line, then inverse case-insensitive grep, and append to file
    ls "$line" | grep -iv '[.]jpg$' >> _command_output.log
done < directories.txt
```

If you want to include hidden files/directories in output (i.e., if you want to include files/directories with filenames starting with `.`), replace `ls` with `ls -a`.

The `-i` option of `grep` turns on case-insensitivity, and `-v` turns on inverse matching (both `-i` and `-v` are POSIX options).

My script assumes that `directories.txt` only contains directories.

---

**Tangential: What the heck does `line="${HOME}/${line#"~/"}"` do?**

The complicated `line="${HOME}/${line#"~/"}"` is based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399439/392334).

Here is an explanation, in case my link dies one day. When the shell interpreter looks at `line="${HOME}/${line#"~/"}"`, it sees:

1. `${HOME}` and `${line#"~/"}` must be expanded.
2. `${HOME}` is expanded to the content of the `$HOME` variable.
3. `${line#"~/"}` triggers a nested expansion: `"~/"` is parsed but, being quoted, is treated as a literal. You could have used single quotes here with the same result.
4. `${line#"~/"}` expression itself is now expanded, resulting in the prefix `~/` being removed from the value of `$line`.
5. The result of the above is now concatenated: the expansion of `${HOME}`, the literal `/`, the expansion `${line#"~/"}`.
6. The end-result is enclosed in double-quotes, functionally preventing word splitting.

Comment: If this is the question the OP is asking, it should be closed as a duplicate; this is already covered in [How to manually expand a special variable, ex. tilde, in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963716/how-to-manually-expand-a-special-variable-ex-tilde-in-bash). See the *Answer Well-Asked Questions* section of [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), particularly the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The OP wasn't asking about tilde expansion. I just wanted to be sure I explained each part of my script.