# Using ! operator on a shell command

Tags: shell, operators

I'm trying to write a script which does something if a particular string is not present in a file.

I know that in order to check if string is available, we can do something like:

```
if grep -qi "sms" $FILE; then
```

But how do I combine a `!` operator with a shell command?

Comment: Which shell so you use?

Comment: or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552711/how-to-make-if-not-true-condition/10552775 . ;-) Good luck.

Comment: @anubhava `grep -v` returns true if any output is produced not if any lines match the inverted filter and are dropped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add it in front of your condition to make it evaluate on the contrary:

```
if ! grep -qi "sms" $FILE; then echo "yes"; fi
   ^
```

#### Test

```
$ cat a
hello
bye
$ if ! grep -qi "sms" a; then echo "sms not found"; fi
sms not found
```

Comment: @fedorqui Thanks. It works. I was trying !grep earlier. Apparently I have to leave a space between ! and grep.

Comment: Nice to read that! Note that `!` is a keyword itself, so to make it work you need to make it be differentiated by the other keywords in action. That is, it needs a space around.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` makes "success" to become "failure" and vice versa from shell points of view. In shell you can also use `&&` (logical and operation), `||` (logical or operation) and group expressions using curly braces `{ ... }`. For example:

```
{ grep root /etc/passwd && ! grep user /etc/passwd; } && echo ok || echo not ok
```

Remember to put `;` before `}`. See `man sh` for more details.

Note that above is a plain shell expression with if-else-like logic. If you want to use `test` command or `[` or `[[` then you can also use other type of grouping, boolean arithmetics and other functions. See `man test`.